# Assigning custom week number in R

Tags: r

I have a data set which has order date starting from 01/07/2017 to 30/06/2018.
I want to extract the week number .I want to assign week number 01 for the days corresponding to 01/07 to 07/07 and so on. I have used the lubridate package but it takes the 01/01 as the starting point.Is there a way to set the offset value ?
My code:

```
order$start_week_date <-  floor_date(as.Date(order$order_date), 
unit="week" , week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 1))
order$week_no <-   strftime( order$start_week_date ,format="%V")
```

Comment: I don't completely understand. Are any of the days repeated? If not, a quick fix may be something like `sort(rep(1:52, 7))`. Otherwise the solution from JonnyCrunch looks adaptable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you like this approach?

```
customweek <- function(dateweek, dateorigin){
  return(as.integer(round((ymd(dateweek)-ymd(dateorigin)  + 1)/7,0)))
}
```

dataweek will be your date and dateorigin your starting point (both in YYYY/MM/DD format).
Therefore:

```
 customweek("20170107", "20170101")
```

Produces 1 as result.

Comment: Nice approach :). Maybe use `ceiling` instead of `round` if I understand correctly. Also, it looks like the date format is in dmy in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably use a function like the following, which uses R's integer division operator, `%/%`, to compute the number of weeks from the number of days post-origin:

```
library(lubridate)

f <- function(date, origin) {
    (as.numeric(dmy(date) - dmy(origin)) %/% 7) + 1
}

## Try it out
dd <- c("01/07/2017", "07/07/2017", "08/07/2017", "30/06/2018")
f(dd, origin = "01/07/2017")
## [1]  1  1  2 53
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your data to an `xts` object and use the power of the `index` attribute.

```
# mock-up data
data <- data.frame(dates=seq(from = as.Date("2017-07-01"), to = as.Date("2018-06-30"), by = "days"), data = rnorm(length(dates)))


# load libraries
library(xts) # a powerful library that makes work with time series pretty easy
library(dplyr)

# create an xts object (an xts object is formed by the matrix of observations, ordered by an index of dates)
df_xts <- xts(data[,-1], order.by = data$dates)

data <- data %>%
# use ".indexweek" to return the week number since beginning of 1970
  mutate(week_nr = .indexweek(df_xts)) %>%
# assign week number starting from 1
  mutate(week_nr = week_nr - min(week_nr) + 1) %>%
# maybe add 0 in front of weeks 1-9
  mutate(week_nr = ifelse(week_nr < 10, paste0("0", week_nr), week_nr))
```

Output:

```
> head(data)
       dates        data week_nr
1 2017-07-01 -0.99142495      01
2 2017-07-02  0.19130095      01
3 2017-07-03 -0.03775566      02
4 2017-07-04  1.24858796      02
5 2017-07-05  0.59453045      02
6 2017-07-06 -0.18317437      02
```